# CSS covering content inside internal html-tag

Tags: html, css, stylesheet, forum, stylish

I'm currently making a custom CSS for a forum (diskusjon.no), but I've been struggling with a certain part of the page. The editor in the IPBoard-forum is a html-tag inside the original html-tag, and my CSS set through the extension [Stylish](http://userstyles.org/stylish) doesn't reach this part of the page.

The structure is something like this:

```
<<html> <---lots of tags--> <iframe> <html> <body contenteditable=true>
```

Now my style affects everything except what's after the second html-tag, so my question is; -is it possible to reach this part of the page at all when I'm adding my CSS through Stylish. i.e. I don't have access to any of the HTML.

Here's a picture of the Google Inspector for the part I'm talking about: [image]

Answer (score 2):

Since the `<iframe>` tag is intended to load an external page, it will have it's own style-sheets. Then, your style cannot interfere with it.

The solution is to use javascript after the page has been loaded into the iframe. You can refer to this: [How to apply CSS to iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/217776/how-to-apply-css-to-iframe) question.

Comment: JavaScript is not needed, nor is it even applicable to a ***Stylish*** problem.

Answer (score 1):

Stylish treats a page the same whether it's in an iframe or not. So, the solution is just to style the iFramed bit separately.

For example, suppose you had the page [**jsbin.com/osajuz/edit**](http://jsbin.com/osajuz/edit#html), and it contained this iFrame:

```
<iframe src="http://www.drudgereport.com/"></iframe>
```

Then you could create a Stylish style like:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document url("http://jsbin.com/osajuz") {
    body {
        background-color: pink;
    }
}

@-moz-document url("http://www.drudgereport.com/") {
    body {
        background-color: lime !important;
    }
}
```

which works.

If you create the style and visit [**jsbin.com/osajuz**](http://jsbin.com/osajuz), you will see something like this:

[image: iFrame style preview]

---

---

Likewise, if the frame has no URL, it is treated as a page from the same domain and URL as the containing page.  Stylish rules will still apply.

For example, if you create this Stylish style:

```
@namespace url(http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml);

@-moz-document domain("jsbin.com") {
    body {
        color: orange;
    }
}

@-moz-document url-prefix("http://jsbin.com/abazay/3/edit") {
    body {
        background: lime;
    }
}
```

and then visit [jsbin.com/abazay/3/edit#preview](http://jsbin.com/abazay/3/edit#preview), you will see both styles applied to both "internal" iFrames.

But **note** that whatever JS is operating an iFrame can override CSS styles if you are not careful.  Therefore make liberal use of the `!important` flag to combat this problem.

Comment: The iframe is internal, and got no URL (as seen in the picture). How could I then reach it with my CSS without using JS as mentioned?

Comment: It's the same, see my updated answer.  Note that you probably need to use `!important` in your styles.

Comment: Thanks, I can see that the contents of the iFrames on your example are affected by my Stylish-style, but I can't port it to the page I'm working on.

I still can't manage to affect the contents of the iFrame I'm trying to edit.
I did a domain/url-prefix and body/body.withRTL + background: lime!important in every combination possible and it still wouldn't set the background in the editor as lime.

The iFrame got it's own style-tag, but should doing !important override this? I'm confused as to how I could "reach" the body-tag inside the iFrame when doing body/body.withRTL doesn't work.

Comment: Link to the page in question.  If that is not possible, or it requires a login, save the HTML and CSS and JS to http://pastebin.com and link to that here.  I don't know what you mean by "body/body"; that would be improper. Stylish "reaches" the iFrame body because it fires at a lower level in FF, and iFrame content looks just like a new webpage to Stylish.  This is different than JS.  The key is to think of the iFrame as a standalone webpage and style it with that in mind. No special CSS rules are needed.